# Таймер возврата на главную страницу

Tags: jquery

Нужен простой таймер возврата на главную страницу. Суть: при открытом модальном окне, в котором отображаются кнопки выбора разделов, инициировать клик на кнопку возврата на главную страницу. Примерно так:

```
if ($('.sections').css('opacity') == '1') {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.close-animatedSectionsRu').trigger('click');
    }, 10000);
}
```

Видимо, здесь с синтаксисом что-то не так. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: что за модальное окно? если используете bootstrap - у них есть ивенты открытия/закрытия окна, и не надо колхозить с открытием ничего. Ну и просто js с данным условием не будет вызывать таймаут

Comment: нее, не boorstrap, использую animatedmodal.js. И вот лично мне достаточно кнопки назад для закрытия и возврата на главную страницу. Но это тестовое задание, в котором написано: "Таймер возврата на главную страницу. Если пользователь не использует Информационную станцию, происходит возврат на главную страницу." Так что приходится колхозить, так как js я в принципе плохо знаю. Может, что посоветуете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log("opacity =", $('.sections').css('opacity'), +$('.sections').css('opacity'));
if (+$('.sections').css('opacity') == 1) {
  ...
```